# Getting a working .NET web service to be consumed by php via SOAP

Tags: php, .net, web-services

I have a .net web service that is standard SOAP, as well as I've added the POST/GET ability to. In .net I can consume the web service without any problems and when using the test POST page I can successfully use the web service as well. I've had a request from a php developer to use the web service which I thought would not be a problem at all, however he is unable to get a successful result. I have never used PHP so I don't have a test project I can even use for the php side of things. I believe it's the first web service he's ever used so he doesn't have a lot of experience himself.

So my questions are:

1) As a .net developer I'm stumped on how to even begin looking at the problem. I do not know if it's a problem in my web service or a problem in his php code. Because .net and POST work I'm inclined to believe it's something in his code, however I'm unable to test because I do not know php.

2) Is there some tag or something I need to do to allow php to correctly use my service?

3) Is there any tool I can use to check compatability with php?

4) Can someone with PHP knowledge look over his code and see if there are any obvious problems?

SOLVED:
Please see working code in answer.

Comment: Use `echo $client->__getLastRequest();` and show what it prints. Specifically, check that the three input params are present in the request.

Comment: @MrCode I tried this, using a PHP script test page (http://writecodeonline.com/php/) and here is the result: 1db1c37d-b181-443e-8cfb-c4574c1245d955184d93-771a-44d1-ba7a-fd02fe1e15f5. Clearly there's only 2 guids present there. Sure seems like that could be the problem. Do you see anything wrong with the array decleration code?

Comment: `__getLastRequest()` should give you the entire XML for the request. You might need to view the source to see it in a browser (because it may hide the xml). Update the question with the full XML request, so we can see the whole thing.

Comment: @MrCode Sorry, please see the original question for the xml request code. It's clearly missing 1 parameter. It appears to be dropping the first declared param, VendorID. Any ideas?

Comment: @MrCode I got it working! I started looking into the soap xml and looking up more php code and I was able to piece together working code.

Comment: You mentioned the following "and when using the test POST page I can successfully use the web service as well. " which make me thing that all the parameters to the webservice are primitive data type and not a complex object.  If that is the case,  do a view source on the test form and grab all the html code from <form .... to </form>.  This should give you all the info that you need to do a basic http post from the php page.  I do this with all of our partner that use php so they can consume it.  You can also create a .aspx page that they can post to and then consume the webservice there.

Comment: @atbebtg Interesting and thank you for that suggestion. I'm going to look into your suggestion if nothing else but to know another way to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$function = "soapcall"; 
$array =array("Param1" => "parameter1", "Param2" => "parameter2", "Param3" => "parameter3"); 

$client = new SOAPClient( 
'http://url.asmx?WSDL', 
array( 
    'location' => 'url.asmx?WSDL', 
    'trace' => 1, 
    'style' => SOAP_RPC, 
    'use' => SOAP_ENCODED, 
) 
);


$result = $client->__soapCall('soapcall', array("parameters"=>$array));

foreach( $result as $r) 
{   print $r."<br>";    }
```

Answer (score 0):

there's a certain lack of interoperability with WCF and other web services - this isn't just a PHP thing, Java libraries often fail to work with WCF web services too. There more information in many other SO questions - see the sidebar.

One thing you could try is [SOAPUI](http://www.soapui.org/) (or [from sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/soapui/files/)) to call your web service 'interactively' which should help him figure out web services.

Comment: Thanks for the SOAPUI link, it looks like that will come in very handy to help diagnose this.

Comment: I have dl'd and installed SOAPUI and my web service has passed the WS-I compliance. I've also ran numereous tests/requests and everything seems to be working as intended. At this point I've got to assume that this is an issue with PHP not playing nicely with SOAP.

Answer (score 0):

We use [NuSoap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/) for webservice calls in Php and it works very well.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I'll pass it along.

Answer (score 0):

.NET Service need to have http endpoints(adapter). 
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50698

Also sometime you need to have NTLM authorization [Call webservice with NTLM authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19541462/call-webservice-with-ntlm-authorization)